# ubuntu karmic 9.10 samba share problem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, samba

I am trying to debug a samba share problem with ubuntu 9.10.

Ubuntu 9.10 shares a folder, try to access from WinXP.
WinXP can't see the folder.

Use netstat -anp command I found that smbd is only accept socket connection on 139 on tcp6 but not in tcp. (IPv4).   **Do anyone know if this is the cause the my connection problem?  If so, how to fix this?**

On the working samba share system (FC11), I can see the smbd is waiting in tcp port 139 and not in tcp6.

Thank

```
root@tlee-vm:~# netstat -anp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1024/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1281/cupsd
tcp       16      0 192.168.64.141:58996    10.81.24.191:445        ESTABLISHED 3647/gvfsd-smb
tcp       24      0 127.0.1.1:40058         127.0.1.1:139           ESTABLISHED 3677/gvfsd-smb-brow
tcp        0      0 192.168.18.140:22       192.168.18.1:4107       ESTABLISHED 3953/sshd: tlee [pr
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      3104/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1024/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1281/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      3104/smbd
tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:139           127.0.1.1:40058         ESTABLISHED 3679/smbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:47032           0.0.0.0:*                           891/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           891/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 192.168.18.140:137      0.0.0.0:*                           3100/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.64.140:137      0.0.0.0:*                           3100/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                           3100/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.18.140:138      0.0.0.0:*                           3100/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.64.140:138      0.0.0.0:*                           3100/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                           3100/nmbd
```

Comment: is samba binding to the interfaces properly?  please include your samba config (`smb.conf`) so we can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had to run `smbpasswd` to add the user password because Samba doesn't automatically copy the Unix passwords into its password backend.

See [`man smb.conf`](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) for specifics on each smb.conf parameter.  The `unix password sync` option doesn't *replace* Samba's password backend with the system password subsystem.  It augments it by allowing your `passwd program` to run when the smbpasswd is changed.  Here's [the specifics](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#UNIXPASSWORDSYNC) from the manpage (emphasis mine).

> This boolean parameter controls whether Samba **attempts to synchronize
>   the UNIX password with the SMB password *when the encrypted SMB password
>   in the smbpasswd file is changed.*** If this is set to yes the program specified
>   in the passwd program parameter is called AS ROOT - to allow the new UNIX password
>   to be set without access to the old UNIX password (as the SMB password change code
>   has no access to the old password cleartext, only the new).
>
> Default: *unix password sync = no*

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by:

Disable the ipv6 in Ubuntu:  (Not sure if I need this step, but I don't need ipv6 anyway and not sure why samba is not binding the ipv4 port)

```
vi /etc/sysct.conf # and add following line; reboot
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

Use the smbpasswd to add the password for the user that need the login,  I am not sure why this is needed, since my /etc/samba/smb.conf file has "unix password sync = yes" line in it.

```
security = user

encrypt passwords = true

passdb backend = tdbsam

obey pam restrictions = yes

unix password sync = yes

passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
```

**BTW, if someone can tell me why I need to use smbpasswd to add the user password to the system, I will mark that as the answer.**

Answer (score 0):

I just had to debug a problem connecting to a samba share on Ubuntu 9.10 from Windows XP, and I found this description of [setting up samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba) helpful, along with this [samba troubleshooting guide](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch12_:_Samba_Security_and_Troubleshooting).

In case you're curious, my firewall on Ubuntu was blocking access. I allowed access on port 445, and it started working.

```
sudo ufw allow 445
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ufw allow 445`

This worked for me. Thanks!

P.S. They need to sort this out. A new linux user would never be able to figure this out!